# How do I get logs for an Elastic Beanstalk environment in a different app than my current app from the command line?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I would like to fetch the logs for a different app. I would expect something like

```
eb --app other-app staging-environment
```

It already allows you to select the environment. `eb logs --help` shows nothing relevant. Or I would expect something like

```
aws elasticbeanstalk logs --app other-app --env staging
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic beanstalk is not really suited for switching between applications as all the commands work in the context of the same app. That being said, this being AWS, you can always make it work with some extra bash scripts. You can use something like the following:

```
mkdir eb-apps && cd eb-apps
mkdir app1 app2 app3
cd app1 && eb init # configure your app
cd app2 && eb init
...

function getLogs() {
  app=$1
  pushd eb-apps/$app
  eb logs
  popd
}
```